# Reading numbers from file in Python, ignoring b'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to read a list of numbers from a url using Python, ex:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,2,3,2,3
etc
```

I tried:

```
list.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')])
```

But I'm using Python 3.2 and this gives error: "TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API" because Python 3 reads input as bytes.

So I tried converting the line to a string:

```
list.append([int(n) for n in str(line).strip().split(',')])
```

but now I have b' at the beginning of each line with the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'1"

Is there an elegant way to get these numbers or do I need to capture the string, strip the first two characters, and convert to int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *decode* the bytes to text:

```
line = line.decode('ascii')
```

*Then* split the line and convert to integers:

```
list.append([int(n) for n in line.split(',')])
```

`int()` can handle extra whitespace, so stripping isn't really needed.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you (I will accept your answer when I can)